# how can I get formatted address

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I get formatted address like ***Covington, AL, USA*** of google web service in my iphone

from the below url 
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=31.319016,-86.399871&sensor=false

Comment: Err, parse the XML and extract the `<formatted_address>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) getAddress
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=31.319016,-86.399871&sensor=false"]];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    NSString *str = [[[dict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];
    NSLog(@"Address = %@", str);

}
```

Use this json this is much faster that xml.

Comment: i want this one Covington, AL, USA bcoz every time index change when location change

Comment: You are Right. Json this is much faster that xml.